# How to minimize Google Cloud launch latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a persistent server that unpredictably receives new data from users, needing about 10 GPU instances to crank at the problem for about 5 minutes, and I send the answer back to the users.    The server itself is a cheap always-persistent single CPU Google Cloud instance. When a user request comes in, my code launches my 10 created but stopped Google Cloud GPU instances with

```
gcloud compute instances start (instance list)
```

In the rare case if the stopped instances don't exist (sometimes they get wiped) that's detected and they're recreated with

```
gcloud beta compute instances create (...)
```

This system all works fine.  My only complaint is that even with created but stopped instances, the launch time before my GPU code finally starts to run is about 5 minutes. Most of this is just the time for the instance itself to launch its Ubuntu host and call my code.. the delay once Ubuntu is running to start the GPU is only about 10 seconds.

How can I reduce this 5 minute delay? I imagine most of it comes from Google having to copy over the 4GB of instance data to the target machine, but the startup time of (vanilla) Ubuntu adds probably 1 more minute.  I'm not even sure if I could quantify these two numbers independently, I only can measure the combined 3-7 minutes delay from the launch until my code starts responding.

I don't think Ubuntu OS startup time is the major startup latency contributor since I timed an actual machine with the same Ubuntu and same GPU on my desk from poweron boot up and it began running my GPU code in 46 seconds.

My goal is to get results back to my users as soon as possible, and that 5 minute startup delay is a bottleneck.

Would making a smaller instance SIZE of say 2GB help?  What else can I do to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2GB is large. That's a heckuva big image. You should be able to cut that down to 100MB, perhaps using Alpine instead of Ubuntu.

Copying 4GB of data is also less than ideal. Given that, I suspect the solution will be more of an architecture change than a code change.

But if you want to take a whack at everything which is NOT about your 4GB of data, there is a capability to prepare a custom image for your VMs. If you can build a slim custom image that will help.

There's good resources for learning more, the two I would start with include:
- [Improve GCE Boot Times with Custom Images](https://medium.com/google-cloud/improving-gce-boot-times-with-custom-images-f77921a2c115)
- [Three steps to Compute Engine startup-time bliss: Google Cloud Performance Atlas](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/07/three-steps-to-Compute-Engine-startup-time-bliss-Google-Cloud-Performance-Atlas.html)

Comment: It turns out that Google Cloud's minimum disk size is 10GB, even for additional mounted disks. So there's not much hope in fixing the latency by shrinking the boot disk size if you're already at the 10GB minimum.

Comment: @DianeWilbor this is a bit of a pain-point which i think Google also is trying to work around. Sounds crazy, but I think it's true. Perhaps as a way of skirting around, or getting Kube-phobic people to do containers, Google is making changes all the time with this...I just learned about this yesterday, it might just be some in-between option `gcloud compute instances create-with-container`.